# Integration testing with aerospike?

Tags: java, integration-testing, aerospike

I would like to write java integration tests which loads an embedded aerospike db during my build process.

I find no such resource of embedded aerospike, is there any other no-sql equivalent to aerospike's api that I can use as embedded?

Comment: Hello.  Did anybody compared Aerospike to Hyperdex in terms of speed or features?

Comment: You can check this solution https://github.com/getintent/embedded-aerospike it uses dcoker and help us to write integration tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Chronicle Map depending on your requirements.  [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) gives you a `Map` which is optionally persisted, remote or replicated.

Note: like Chronicle Map, AerospikeDB is engineered for performance and there is few which are [A list of alternatives are here](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/chronicle-map-and-yahoo-cloud-service.html)

Disclaimer: I am the lead developer for this product.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
I can see that Chronicle Map have fully support of Maven which is great for me.

However, it is still a problem for me to use it, because it doesn't expose exactly the same API of aerospike.

Comment: @agavish I suspect only aerospike has exactly the interface.

Comment: I have made a aerospike-unit module, which one can use while writing unit, Integration test cases . (Java Project)

This is a Java wrapper over actual Aerospike Server which can be used for unit + Integration Testing .

Open Source CodeBase: https://github.com/maverickgautam/Aerospike-unit

Readme available at https://github.com/maverickgautam/Aerospike-unit/blob/master/README
Hope Aerospike community finds this useful .

Comment: @KrazyGautam This is an excellent contribution.